# Tweak CSS Validation in Adobe Flex Builder (Eclipse)

Tags: css, apache-flex, validation, adobe, flexbuilder

I am getting a number of spurious warnings in my CSS files within my Flex project.  Any way to tweak which warnings are displayed in Eclipse like I do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/10/filtering-bookmarks-warnings-and-errors.html